# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /var/www/html

Tags: docker, selenium, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting this error from the docker command in Jenkins selenium testing. However, when I test run the command locally on my computer, it works.

[image]

Comment: Please avoid pasting screenshots of the code and terminal output. Paste the text, text is great!

Comment: Is you Jenkins installed on windows?

Comment: yes, it is installed